# Does CDH 6.3.2 yarn have Resource or node restrictions？

Tags: hadoop-yarn, cloudera-cdh

Our CDH cluster version is 6.3.2, and the original cluster size is 26 Nodemanagers. However, after the expansion of two nodes, it is found that YARN resources are limited, and max AM Resouces in the fair scheduler queue becomes small. Cause a large number of application pending, I do not know whether CDH has any special restrictions on YARN or CDH resources.

We would like to know what resource restrictions CDH 6.3.2 has, thank you